# How to set up an ODBC connection to a pervasive database with Yii2?

Tags: yii2, odbc

I have basically managed to connect to a pervasive database with Yii2, through ODBC. The system DSN named **demodata** was already (actually twice) predefined (as 32-bit using the driver: Pervasive ODBC Client Interface (which I dont have when I'm trying to set up a new connection by the way...), and as a 64-bit platform as well, using the driver: Pervasive ODBC Interface, so I'm not sure which one is being used actually, but after renaming one of them it's pretty sure that only the 32-bit version is working, otherwise I'm getting the same error as down below), so it was already there.

This is my OdbcController:

```
public function actionIndex() {
    try {
        $odbc = odbc_connect("Driver={Pervasive ODBC Interface};ServerName=localhost;ServerDSN=DEMODATA;", "", "");
        $result = odbc_tables($odbc);
        var_dump(odbc_fetch_array($result));
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

The result looks like this:

```
array (size=5)
  'TABLE_QUALIFIER' => string 'DEMODATA' (length=8)
  'TABLE_OWNER' => null
  'TABLE_NAME' => string 'Billing' (length=7)
  'TABLE_TYPE' => string 'TABLE' (length=5)
  'REMARKS' => null
```

So it seems like there is only one single table in this db.

Now I would like to set up a new System DSN in ODBC in order to get all the tables from the main db. When I click on **add**, and then choose **Pervasive ODBC Interface** (the only other driver from Actian would be **Pervasive ODBC Unicode Interface** which doesn't make any difference) and on **get list**, I'm getting:

- DEFAULTDB
- DEMODATA
- TEMPDB

Of course I'm trying to use DEFULTDB, because it seems the only reasonable option. When I test the connection it says successful. However when I change my controller to DEFAULTDB, I'm getting this error message:

Connection failed: odbc_connect(): SQL error: [Zen][ODBC Client Interface][LNA][Zen][SQL Engine][Data Record Manager]Non-db file or corrupted db., SQL state S1000 in SQLConnect

How could I create a connection to the main pervasive db? There is another app that's basically and certainly using the db I'm looking for, with many tables, but I'm not sure if it's DEFAULTDB or something else. How could I find out what dbs are there? Can you please pont me to the right direction?

UPDATE: ok it's pretty sure that only the 32 bit driver is working, and i'm unfortunately not an "32-Bit-ODBC-Datasource-Administrator" so I can't configure or check this connection what the settings are.

UPDATE: I've figured it out that there is a 32 bit version of the ODBC application in Windows as well, so I've managed to create a 32 bit connection to the DB DEFAULTDB, however the result is only this:

```
array (size=5)
  'TABLE_QUALIFIER' => string 'DEFAULTDB' (length=9)
  'TABLE_OWNER' => null
  'TABLE_NAME' => string 'X$Attrib' (length=8)
  'TABLE_TYPE' => string 'SYSTEM TABLE' (length=12)
  'REMARKS' => null
```

I still don't think that this is the right DB I'm looking for, or is it possible that I'm just not retrieving all information about it with this command?

Comment: You are only retrieving one row (representing one table) from the results. You have to call `odbc_fetch_array()` in cycle to retrieve multiple rows. See the first example here https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-tables.php

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to check this right away! And which driver do I need actually: Pervasive ODBC [ Client | Engine | Unicode ] Interface?